# C++ | Mysql запрос в базу данных

Tags: c++, mysql

Пробую делать Mysql запрос в базу данных (НЕ localhost), не проходит. Подозреваю, что ошибка в адресе бд (Некорректным образом указываю)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Если пишу неправильно- прошу исправить / кинуть материал :D

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int qstate;

int main(){
    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES* res;
    conn = mysql_init(0);

    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "a363322.mysql.mchost.ru", "name", "pass", "a363322_1", 3306, NULL, 0);
    if (conn) {
        puts("Successful connection to database!");

        string query = "SELECT * FROM akylka";
        const char* q = query.c_str();
        qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
        if (!qstate)
        {
            res = mysql_store_result(conn);
            while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
            {
                printf("ID: %s, Name: %s, Value: %s\n", row[0], row[1], row[2]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Query failed: " << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        puts("Connection to database has failed!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Надо полагать, что бд не слушает запросы из интернета.

Comment: А что насчет посмотреть логи базы? Получает она запрос или нет?